# Is Spring ever going to combine MVC and WebFlow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I thought I read Juergen Holler somewhere once in the past say that a future goal of Spring was to combine Spring MVC and WebFlow...

Is this still the case?

At the moment they still seem to be fairly separate projects, with WebFlow being recommended as an EXTENSION to MVC. As a developer it would be great if I could use both and define all my controllers in the same way (either Java or XML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm [here's](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/04/20/spring-web-flow-project-update/) something I found:

Web Flow 3 ... you can expect to see the introduction of a @Flow model that compliments Spring MVC's stateless @Controller model and allows stateful web flows to be defined as POJOs.